# Google maps reverse geocoding getting exception on consecutive clicks

Tags: android, google-maps, android-asynctask, google-geocoder

I'm using an Asynctask to reverse geocode a user marked location in Google maps.I handle the eception inside the Async,but when consecutive clicks are done on the map,the app is getting crashed.

I used the example code from [here](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-reverse-geocoding-at-touched-location-in-google-map-android-api-v2/)

Comment: can you post the log of the exception? Otherwise is quite impossible to help

Comment: its a null pointer exception caught at the click event...@NDorigatti

Comment: i see, but log tells you which row fires the exception, that row is the problem.
Null pointer exception means you are trying to access a null object. Just set a breakpoint at the first row of the the clicklistener and debug it. With no log we can't help you